# Python : How to read all files in the directory with some specific condition?

Tags: python, file, directory, glob

I want to read all the files in one directory. Directory contains following files:

```
ABC11_1.csv
ABC11_3.csv
ABC11_2.csv
ABC13_4.csv
ABC13_1.csv
ABC17_6.csv
ABC17_2.csv
ABC17_4.csv
ABC17_8.csv
```

When I'm running my script I want to give this file name on the console in the format as : 
**ABC11.**

After that I want to read all the files with only ABC11 extensions in the sorted order. i.e. first ABC11_1.csv,ABC11_2.csv,ABC11_3.csv like that.

If user gives only ABC application must have to give error message. If user gives only ABC1 then it is valid application accept this and check in the directory for files with the extension ABC1, if available then process the files in sorted order,if not then error message.

**Program-Code-**

```
from glob import glob
import os
import sys

file_pattern = ''
files_list = list()
arguments = {'ABC', 'PQR', 'XYZ'}

if len(sys.argv[1:2]) is 1:
   file_pattern = str(sys.argv[1:2])
else:   
   print 'run as <python test.py ABC>'
   sys.exit(1)
if file_pattern in arguments:
   print '<Provide LineName with some Number>'
   sys.exit(1)

file_pattern = file_pattern.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','')

if file_pattern.startswith('ABC',0,3):
   files_list = glob(os.path.join('<directory name>', str(file_pattern)+'_*.csv'))
else:
   print 'No Such File --> ' + str(file_pattern)+ '\t  <Provide appropriate Name>'
   sys.exit(1)

if files_list:
   for a_file in sorted(files_list):
      print a_file
     #process file
else:
   print 'No Such File --> ' + str(file_pattern)+ '\t  <Provide appropriate Name>'
   sys.exit(1)
```

I'm doing like that and it work's fine for me but is that other best ways to do this stuff. Please provide all your responses?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

According to your question, following pseudo code should work

```
import os 

# Read all files from a directory, and read your input argument
files = os.listdir("your_input_directory_path")
input_argument = "ABC11"

# Sort file names by name
files = sorted(files) 

relevant_files = []
for file_name in files:
    # Your Conditions goes here ........

    if file_name.startswith(input_argument):
        relevant_files.append(file_name)



if relevant_files:
    return "Error | Not Found"
else:
    return relevant_files
```

Comment: @userxxx- Is it fulfill all my requirements which I provided in the question?

Comment: Yes, try running this code.. there may be some minor change according to your requirement. But I guess this will work according to whatever you have mentioned in your question

Comment: @userxxx- If user give ABC1 argument so it should check for only ABC1_ (whaterver) file. It should not return ABC11_1.csv file.